# An Anime Short Film about living on the moon and a guy is sorting a database filled with earth history and a woman singing an earth song

Tags: story-identification, anime, short-film

I need help in identifying an anime that I watched a few years ago. It's an ONA (or an OVA) about this one guy sorting Earth's history in a moon base (or I think is sort of revealed in the end). And he's listening to a recording of a song. He's doing this for a long time and from what I recall, he got curious and like saw a way to reveal the truth and found an elevator of sorts which launched himself out of the moon base and saw that he isn't on Earth and in fact, is on the moon. He saw the Earth outside the moon base. I also distinctly remember that he found out that the song he is listening to came from an female musician after arriving on the moon.

This is just one episode and I think it's technically a short film. I'm sorry if I'm not clear since it has been like half a decade to a decade when I watched it.

Comment: ONA? Ontario Nurses Association? OVA? Organic Vapor Analyzer? PDNUCA, TYVMA.

Comment: Oh, sorry! ONA = Original Net Animation, OVA = Original Video Animation. ONAs are usually anime uploaded on the internet while if I recall correctly, OVAs are those anime that is released with bluray formats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably "Pale Cocoon" (2006), a one-off OVA anime written and directed by Yasuhiro Yoshiura.

ANN synopsis:

> A future where the continuity of history has broken off, a world of
> enormous ruins that continues endlessly. Oceans and continents have
> vanished, existing only within the archives brought up from the
> remains. Ura works in the Archive Excavation Department, which
> restores and analyzes the data left behind. One day, he finds a
> disturbing visual record...

Quote from a fan-sub spoiler file:

> What Ura is doing through the film (most of it is flashback) is
> climbing up the stairs to the upper levels of the "world". Then he
> takes a rocket elevator to up above all of it, to see an artificially
> generated sky. (The clouds and stuff were probably generated from the
> "life sustaining utilities", and floated up to the top to make a thin
> atmosphere). As for the giant rocket, it's probably a remnant of the
> migration ships. And at the end, he sees the Earth from the moon, but
> instead of the rusted earth that humans left ages ago, the earth has
> recovered itself and once more become blue. (This is what YOKO was
> referring to in her music video and interview, she left the earth for
> the moon, and her song "Pale Cocoon" basically is a "prayer" for the
> earth to once again experience morning after a long sleep of
> recovery.)

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thank you!!